# How to migrate Enumfield values in Django properly?

Tags: python, django, django-models, database-migration, django-migrations

Suppose we have an Enum:

```
class MyEnum(Enum):
    FOO = "FOO"  
    BAR = "BAR"  
    BAZ = "BAZ"
```

that is used in a field:

```
from enumfields import EnumField

    class FooModel (models.Model)   
        foo_field = EnumField(
            MyEnum, null=True, blank=True, default=MyEnum.FOO)
```

Then I want to remove one of the fields in `MyEnum`, because I do not want value `FOO` in my database anymore

```
class MyEnum(Enum):
    BAR = "BAR"  
    BAZ = "BAZ"
```

```
from enumfields import EnumField

    class FooModel (models.Model)   
        foo_field = EnumField(
            MyEnum, null=True, blank=True, default=MyEnum.BAR)
```

I need to migrate data, so my migration may look like this:

```
def migrate_not_for_sale_to_private(apps, schema_editor):
    FooModel = apps.get_model("foo", "FooModel")
    for obj in FooModel.objects.all():
        if obj.foo_field == "FOO":
            obj.foo_field = "BAR"
            obj.save()
```

This one fails, because I changed allow values for `foo_field` to `BAR` and `BAZ`, and so if `obj` has value `FOO`, it blows up with not allowed value error.

How one should do it properly? I could leave `MyEnum` values as they are, marking one as legacy, but in a long run it leads to a lot of potential legacy fields. The other way could be running raw SQL command (assume I am using PostgreSQL).

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `default=MyEnum.FOO` to `default=MyEnum.BAR`
2. Block any new `FOO` entries from code
3. Migrate all `FOO` objects to `BAR` from DB
4. Remove the `FOO` enum

About 2., you can overwrite the `def save(self, *args, **kwargs):` function for your `FooModel` to change any new `FOO` objects to `BAR` ones (or raise an error)

Comment: My question is generally speaking "How to do point 3 while simultaneously performed 4" :)

Comment: You can't do it in the same time, otherwise some of your queries will not work in that time.